# error: too few arguments to function 'char* itoa(int, char*, int)' byte blockcontent= itoa(order); ^ In file include

Tags: arduino-uno

I have this statement in my Arduino code :

```
 byte blockcontent [16] = itoa(order);
```

and it gives me an error saying:
"Too few arguments to function 'char*itoa(int,char*,int)'. Even though I've looked for the documentation of itoa function and I found that it accepts one input argument.
Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: Where did you find this documentation, out of interest? The [very first hit I get with Google](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) shows 3 arguments: `char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );`

Comment: @NickGammon https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590395/539490

Comment: That "reference" is just a *question* on Stack Overflow. Underneath that question is the comment: *How does option 1 even work for you at all? It's my understanding that itoa() takes three parameters* - Questions are often asked because people are unsure about what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itoa requires a minimum of 2 arguments.

Reference: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaa571de9e773dde59b0550a5ca4bd2f00

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to set an array pointer instead of character pointer?

Comment: You can probably set a char pointer inside an array of char pointer yes if that is what you mean.